# Not so common HTML transition to wordpress issue

Tags: templates, headers

This is one possibility most of the time:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

But my design is like this where wrap has a flex, and the sidebar and main are horizontally positioned. →

```
<div class="wrap">
    <section class="sidebar">
        <header></header>
        <footer></footer>
    </section>
    <main></main>
</div>
```

Here `header` and `footer` are one after another in the sidebar and the main content is in another container.
How should I transfer this `HTML` into WordPress? I am facing a mental obstacle.

Update →

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <section class="seidebar">
        <header></header>
        <footer></footer>
    </section>
    <main></main>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I have converted the above HTML like this:

header.php →

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div class="wrap">
    <section class="seidebar">
        <header></header>
        <footer></footer>
    </section>
```

Footer.php →

```
  <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

index.php →

```
<main></main>
```

I hope by doing so I am faltering in achieving basic templating. If the answer is yes, then I have got an answer to my queestion.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just write the HTML that way in the templates. Where are you having trouble? Keep in mind that just because an element is _called_ sidebar, does not mean that it _must_ be in sidebar.php.

Comment: Got it to let me convert that into the template.  Some Information is missing for people to comprehend I will add the information tomorrow.

Comment: Question Upated.

Answer (score 1):

At the end every html tag, not self self closing tags, can be used how ever you want.

Want to build a website using only `<span>`, go for it.

Going by symantic html.

A `<section>` can contain a `<header>` and `<footer>`, symantical that is correct.

You can have multiple `<header>` and `<footer>` tags, they should be in the proper parent tags.

Something like this

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav></nav>
    </header>

    <h1></h1>

    <main>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h1></h1>
            </header>
            <div></div>
            <footer></footer>
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

This is a valid html structure, going by the rules of HTML5.

What?! multiple `<h1>` tags... yes, in the era of html5 you can use multiple `<h1>` tags because of symantic tags, if will affect screen readers so you need to add the proper attributes to indecate nested `<h1>` tags, see [–: The HTML Section Heading elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements)

The best place to understand how symantic elemets should be structured, what elements can be children of what elements, is [HTML elements reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)
, there are of course other good resources about HTML5 so keep searching.

About your html5 structure, its a valid structure and will couse no problems.
You can also check your html with [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/), i use this all the time when developing a website to make sure my html is correct and has no problems.

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks.